# Chapter header too big in Legrand Orange Book

Tags: chapters, book-design

I'm writing a laboratory manual using the [Legrand Orange Book](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book) as template. What I've found unattractive in the output is the laaaaarge separation between the header and the start of the main body. The image I've had to use for chapter header must have a 5:1 ratio instead of the recommended 2:1, otherwise it look disproportionate. The only change I've could made is to lift the title a few, making it closer to the header, but I can't lift the main body. Is there a way to do that?

This is an screenshot of the output; I don't have the final chapter head image yet so I've put a placeholder.
[image]

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I've found the way, I'll leave my solution here in case it helps someone in the future.

In the structure.tex file there is a set of code lines that runs the chapter head:

```
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% A switch to conditionally include a picture, implemented by  Christian Hupfer
\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter. #1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=ocre,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}
```

If you change the value in the argument of the `\vspace` command you can lift (or down) the body.

Comment: Please, provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem. Where is available *Legrand Orange Book*  "template"? We can't help you if we not know what you doing/try so far.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't added a MWE because I thought the template was known (I've found a lot of answers here in the past). I've added a link to the template. The only thing I've modified from there is a line to lift the chapter title, and my "problem" was there even before modifying it.

Comment: Well, to help you we still need a MWE. This template is unknown at least to me.  I'm pretty sure, that it is property of someone.

Comment: From your code fragment i guess, that may help if on code line `\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}`  reduce `vspace*` size to some smaller value, for example `\fi\fi\par\vspace*{33\p@}}}`.